# Redis Cache Number of connected clients increasing

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

[image: Azure Portal - Redis Cache - Max Connected Clients]

I am developing a microservice architecture application where I am using a Redis Cache to cache frequently used information. The issue is that the number of connected clients is constantly increasing and I don't know why.

I am accessing the Redis Cache from an ASP.NET Web API and a Web Job. The NuGet package used for connection is "StackExchange.Redis" (https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis).

The way I am connecting to Redis in code is as follows:

```
connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);
connection.ConnectionFailed += ConnectionFailed;
connection.ConnectionRestored += ConnectionRestored;
connection.InternalError += InternalError;

if (!connection.IsConnected)
{
    //_traceSource.TraceWarning($"Connection to REDIS '{_endpointAddress}' was not established.");
}

database = connection.GetDatabase();

return database;
```

In addition, I have implemented the Dispose() method to make sure that connections are disconnected properly:

```
public void Dispose()
{
   connection?.Close(true);
}
```

Comment: Looks like your app creates new connections but doesn't close them

Comment: You should share the same static `ConnectionMultiplexer`

Answer (score 2):

Implement a static Helper class like this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for connection with Redis Server.
/// </summary>
public static class Helper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Configuration option to connect with Redis Database.
    /// </summary>
    private static Lazy<ConfigurationOptions> configOptions = new Lazy<ConfigurationOptions>(() =>
    {
        var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();
        configOptions.EndPoints.Add("Your Redis sever name");
        configOptions.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
        configOptions.AllowAdmin = true;
        configOptions.KeepAlive = 4;
        configOptions.Password = "Redis server password";
        return configOptions;
    });

    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions.Value));

    /// <summary>
    /// Connection property to connect Redis Database.
    /// </summary>
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

After that use it like this wherever you need it.

```
var RedisDatabase = Helper.Connection.GetDatabase(Database Number);
```

This will maintain the connections automatically. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the following 3 steps :

1. Add shutdown hook which calls connection.close().

   Refer : [How to call event before Environment.Exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842077/how-to-call-event-before-environment-exit)

   But it's not [guaranteed to be called](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/11/26/appdomain-processexit-is-not-guaranteed-to-be-called/) always. Hence, #2:
2. Configure Redis with client timeout to close connections idle > some threshold 
   https://redis.io/topics/clients
3. Ensure duplicate connections aren't created unnecessarily. Ex: a new connection is created per call to Redis. @Keyur Ramoliya 's answer seems to address this.